# libreoffice and ubuntu 14.04 gui problem

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I have some problem with libreoffice window resize: [screen after window resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzmQn.png)
I already tried with version 4.2 and 5.0, the result was the same. Any suggestion?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' command output:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3815
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: "some problem"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Libreoffice 5.2 and found a solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1317043).

Apparently, the installation of the meta-package "libreoffice-gnome" (using Ubuntu) was necessary for it in order to work properly.